# How do I achieve this effect the best way possible, using Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: I want to imply what I did in A/B to B/C.]

I want to make what I did between the letters A and B but between the letters B and C. For the first one I used a tiny rectangle and I'm not sure if this is the correct and easiest way to do it as I'm struggling with B and C.

How do I achieve this the most effective way possible and what is this even called in graphic design language?

Comment: It would be called an "offset" possibly, or maybe a "knockout". Are you okay with white in the offset (see Billy's answer) or do you what that offset area to be gone, non-existent, transparent?

Comment: Thanks! I used what Billy suggested, but you're right, I was actually looking for a transparent outcome (didn't really realize at the moment of posting my question). So what I did after applying a stroke was using a Minus Front Pathfinder to make it transparent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the letters are individual text objects, you could apply a white stroke and fill in the Appearance panel. Just make sure you click and drag the fill above the stroke, so that the stroke is behind the fill and doesn't eat into the letter itself.

[image]